# Cómo agregar una restricción para evitar registro de fechas en Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

tengo una duda en cuanto a mi tabla **Capacitación**, tengo estos campos

```
create table Capacitacion (
    id_capacitacion number,
    usuario number,
    fechainicio date,
    fechafinal date
)
```

Ahora, tengo insertado a mi usuario **1** con **fechainicio** el **01/02/18** y **fechafinal** el **05/02/18**

**Acá va mi duda** : quiero ingresar otra capacitación a este mismo usuario (**1**) pero con la restricción de que la nueva **fechainicio** que ingrese deba ser mayor a la **fechafinal** del primer registro (osea mayor a **05/02/18**) sino que **no permita**. Me he quedado estancado hasta acá.

**RESUELTO**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OCEX_CHARLA_VERF
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON OCEX_CHARLA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    obtenerVigenciaCharla   DATE;  
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(VIG_CHAR)
    INTO obtenerVigenciaCharla
    FROM OCEX_CHARLA
    WHERE CIP_PER = :NEW.CIP_PER;

    IF (obtenerVigenciaCharla > :NEW.FEC_CHAR) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20018,'ERROR AL INSERTAR DATA.');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: No es necesario indicar RESUELTO en el título de tu pregunta, en SO basta que marques una respuesta como correcta :)

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle no te lo manejará automáticamente, dentro de la misma fila puedes puedes hacer una constraint `CHECK fila_fecha_1 > fila_fecha_2`

Te recomiendo utilizar un trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_EVITAR_FECHAS_ANTIGUAS
--En vez de insertar en la tabla capacitacion
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Capacitacion 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     --USA UNA VARIABLE PATA LA ULTIMA FECHA INSERTADA
     ultimafecha DATE;

     SELECT ultima_fecha
     INTO ultimafecha
     FROM Capacitaciones
     WHERE
     --- ACÁ CONSTRUYES LA LÓGICA PARA LA CONSULTA
     --- CON EL FINDE OBTENER EL ÚLTIMO INGRESO
     ---  podría ser MAX(FECHA) = FECHA 
     AND ID_USUARIO = NEW:ID_USUARIO;

     IF(ultimafecha >= NEW:NUEVA_FECHA)
     THEN
          --ESTO ES EN CASO QUE EL VALOR SEA IGUAL O MAYOR
          --TIRA UN ERROR O ALGO ASÍ, SI LO ESTIMAS CONVENIENTE
     ELSE
          INSERT INTO Capacitaciones(id,....columnas.....,ultimacolumna)
          VALUES (:new.id, :new.columna1, :new.columna2.....,:new.ultimacolumna);
     END IF;
 END TRG_EVITAR_FECHAS_ANTIGUAS;
```

De otra forma dependiendo de al estructura de tu base de datos a la fila le podrías indicar

```
CHECK FILA_CON_LA_FECHA > SYSDATE;
```

En este caso te aseguras que la fila siempre tenga un valor mayor a la fecha de hoy (o el "hoy" del servidor")
Espero te pueda servir.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me diste una buena idea para poder acabar este trigger que tenía días sin poder resolverlo, adjunto como quedó mi trigger.

Comment: Investiga lo siguiente ya que no recuerdo bien, por lo que veo tu trigger funcionaría bajo la expectativa que tienes, pero al parecer esa query es sensible a la hora por ejemplo `10/10/2018 00:00:01  es menor a 10/10/2018 00:00:02` puede ser que a lo mejor te sea conveniente manejarlo por día. 

Por lo demás se ve bastante bien.

Comment: Así es, registra si la fechafinal y la fechainicio son iguales, te refieres a manejarlo con to_char en vez de to _date?

Comment: No, sigue manejándolos como date, a lo que me refiero es que si las fechas son iguales en el sentido de que sean fechas dentro de un mismo día el registro los pasaría por ejemplo si a las 5.30 de la tarde del día X estaba la fecha final el registro se podría realizar a las 5.31 del mismo día. A lo que voy es que transforma la fecha a TO_DATE (dedundante), pero podrías comparar `TO_DATE(fecha, "DD/MM/YYYY")` de esta forma te aseguras que no puedan registrar dentro del mismo día independiende a la hora. Pero reitero..investiga (no recuerdo tanto, estoy volcado a php ahora)

Comment: Ok gracias por la info, me pongo en ello ahora mismo :)

Comment: una consulta si deseo ingresar una excepción cuando ingrese un nuevo usuario que no tenga charla registrada, he puesto después del IF.....EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN INSERT INTO Capacitación values(...); END; pero me sigue manejando el mismo error.

Comment: Al registrar un usuario nuevo (otra tabla o schema me imagino) lanza la excepción que se relacione a la regla de negocio que tengas.

Comment: Nono, osea cuando quiero registrar en la tabla Capacitación (tabla donde se ejecuta el trigger) si ingreso un nuevo registro y el nuevo **id** no tiene una **capacitación** registrada no la deja registrar y salta el error "No data found"